# repeticion de la vista

Tags: php, mvc, index

Esto hace que se conecte mi bd con mis controladores y me los muestre en mi archivo vista

'''<?php

```
require_once 'config/conexion.php';
require_once 'controllers/usuarioController.php';
require_once 'controllers/EmpleadoController.php';
require_once 'controllers/MedicoController.php';

$usuarioController = new UsuarioController($conn);
$medicoController = new MedicoController($conn);
$empleadoController = new EmpleadoController($conn);

$empleadoController->mostrarEmpleadosPersonaUsuario();
$medicoController->mostrarMedicos();
$usuarioController->mostrarUsuariosConNivelSeguridad();
$usuarioController->mostrarNivelesSeguridad();
```

?>'''

Me esta repitiendo el mismo proceso cuatro veces una por cada mostrar, provocando que mi vista se repita la misma cantidad de veces, y en cada una solo muestra la consula mostrar a la que esta consultando, y en las demas solo los muestra bacios o no los encuentra